# Second-order non-linear 2-variable partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to gain some information on a non-linear partial differential equation by issuing the following Mathematica command:

```
DSolve[ f[x, y] - x D[f[x, y], x, y] == 0 , f[x, y] , {x, y} ]
```

As an answer I just get the same expression. Does that mean that Mathematica cannot come up with any useful information regarding the solution of such equations?

Are there other things I can try? Is anything known about such differential equations?

Thanks in advance,

Uri

P.S. The function Exp[ 2 Sqrt[ y Log[x] ] ] is "almost" a solution of this differential equation.

Comment: this pde is linear. Why do you call it non-linear?

Comment: The second derivative is multiplied by x, which makes it non-linear.

Comment: No. that is wrong. Nonlinearity is on the dependent variable, not the independent variables. The dependent variable enters the pde as linear.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Is there anything you can say regarding the queation itself?

Comment: By $  x \partial_x \to \partial_z $ it is the wave equation $\partial_{z,y}f  =f$.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica can't solve this directly. One way around is to help it a little by using separation of variables. By assuming $f(x,y)= X(x) Y(y)$

```
f[x_,y_]:=X[x]*Y[y];
pde=f[x,y]-x D[f[x,y],x,y]==0
Expand[pde[[1]]/f[x,y]]==0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above shows that we have

$$
x \frac{X'}{X} \frac{ Y'}{Y} = 1
$$
Which is the same as
$$
x \frac{X'}{X}  = \frac{ Y}{Y'}
$$
Hence these both are same and equal to some constant, say $\lambda$ which is the eigenvalue.
$$
x \frac{X'}{X}  = \frac{ Y}{Y'} = \lambda
$$

So we have two ode's to solve

```
ode1=x*X'[x]/X[x]==λ
ode2=Y[y]/Y'[y]==λ
solX  =  DSolveValue[ode1,X[x],x]
solY  =  DSolveValue[ode2,Y[y],y]/.C[1]->C[2]
```

Hence the final solution is

```
solX*solY
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The eigenvalue $\lambda$ can be determined from boundary conditions.

### Verification

To verify that the above solution  is correct

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
sol=f->Function[{x,y},E^(y/λ) x^λ C[1] C[2]]
pde=f[x,y]-x D[f[x,y],x,y]==0
pde/.sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting!

As I said in the post, the function $e^{\sqrt{y \ln x}}$ is "close" to being a solution of the equation. I wonder whether there is an exact solution of a similar form. Such a solution, if it exists, is not separable. Is anything known about non-separable solutions?

Comment: The more general solution is `Integrate[c[λ] E^(y/λ) x^λ, λ]`, where `c` is an arbitrary function of `λ`.